# SQL Exam - estimating table size problem

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I'm preparing to the SQL Server exam (70-431). I have the book from Sybex ["SQL Server 2005 - Implementation and Maintenance"](http://www.sybex.com/WileyCDA/SybexTitle/MCTS-Microsoft-SQL-Server-2005-Implementation-and-Maintenance-Study-Guide-Exam-70-431.productCd-0470025654.html). I'm little confused about estimating a size of a table.

In the 2nd chapter there is explained how to do this:

1. Count the row size from the formula: `Row_Size = Fixed_Data_Size + Variable_Data_Size + Null_Bitmap + Row_Header`.

   - `Fixed_Data_Size` is a sum of all sizes of fixed length columns (simple sum)
   - `Variable_Data_Size = 2 + (num_variable_columns × 2) + max_varchar_size`, `num_variable_columns` - number of columnt with variable length, `max_varchar_size` - maximum size of varchar column
   - `null_bitmap = 2 + ((number of columns + 7) ÷ 8)` (rounded down)
   - `Row_header` always equals `4`.
2. Calculating rows per page from the formula: `Rows_Per_Page = 8096 ÷ (Row_Size + 2)` (rounded down)
3. Estimating the number of rows in the table. Let's say that table has 1,000 rows.
4. Calculating the number of pages needed: `No_Of_Pages = 1,000 / Rows_Per_Page` (rounded up)
5. Total size: `Total_Size = No_Of_Pages * 8,192`, where 8,192 is the size of one page.

So everything is perfectly clear for me. I made one example and checked with the answers in the book that my calculations are correct. But there is one question which confuses me.

The question is: we have a table with the following schema:

```
Name       Datatype
-------------------
ID         Int
VendorID   Int
BalanceDue Money
DateDue    Datetime
```

It is expected that in this table there will be about 5,000 rows. Question (literaly): "How much space will the Receivables table take?"

So my answer is simple:

```
null_bitmap = 2 + ((4+7) / 8) = 3.375 = 3 (rounded)
fixed_datasize =  4 + 4 + 8 + 8 = 24
variable_datasize = 0
row_header = 4 (always)

row_size = 3 + 24 + 0 + 4 = 31
```

But in the answer they omit `row_header` and they don't add `4`. Is it a mistake in the book or `row_header` is added only in some cases (which are not mentioned in the book)? I was thinking that maybe `row_header` is added only if there are variable-length fields in the table, but there is another exercise in which there are not variable-length fields and `row_header` is added. I would appreciate if someone explains me that. Thanks.

Comment: I have no idea, but i will say that i've encountered numerous errors in numerous books :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Inside the Storage Engine: Anatomy of a record](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/post/Inside-the-Storage-Engine-Anatomy-of-a-record.aspx) says all records have a record header:

> The record structure is as follows:
>
> - record header
>
>   - 4 bytes long
>   - two bytes of record metadata (record type)
>   - two bytes pointing forward in the record to the NULL bitmap